# git show email in jenkins pipeline returns wrong

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

From the command line or outside jenkins, and in the folder where git repository is checked out locally, when we run this command  - `git show -s --format='%ae'`  and it does return "correct" email say "acme@example.com".

Coming to  the jenkins pipeline, just after the git clone happens, we are retrieving an email using this below command -

```
def getrecipientEmail = "git show -s --format='%ae'"
env.recipientEmail = sh ( script: getrecipientEmail, returnStdout: true).trim()
env |sort
```

it prints `08:27:33  recipientEmail=nobody@nowhere` , any suggestion to improve in the jenkins pipeline and retrieve an email for those whoever pushed the commit ?